# Multiple one-to-many joins to same table performance

Tags: sql, oracle, join, database-performance

Assume I have table `Client` that's being referenced by multiple tables like `Profile`, `Address`, `Phone`, `Account`... through `client_id` column in all these tables.

So one client may have multiple profiles, multiple addresses and so on.

I need to get all `Client`'s information through single query.

If I write query like

```
SELECT C.*, PR.*, AD.*, PH.*, AC.* FROM CLIENT C 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN PROFILE PF ON C.ID=PF.CLIENT_ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ADDRESS AD ON C.ID=AD.CLIENT_ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN PHONE PH ON C.ID=PH.CLIENT_ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ACCOUNT AC ON C.ID=AC.CLIENT_ID
```

and account has 10 profiles, 10 addresses, 10 phones and 10 accounts I'd end up with 10000 (10x10x10x10) rows in my resultset, though I'd need only 40 (10+10+10+10).

Should I better write multiple queries or there's simple way to make database produce less rows?

Upd: added sample data:

`Client`

```
ID     | Name       | ...
------ | -----------|-----
1      | "John Doe" |
```

`Profile`

```
ID     | CLIENT_ID | TYPE        | ...
------ | --------- | ----------- | ---
1      | 1         | "Primary"   |
2      | 1         | "Secondary" |
3      | 1         | "Work"      |
4      | 1         | "Office"    |
5      | 1         | "Vacation"  |
...
```

'Address'

```
ID     | CLIENT_ID | ADDRESS_TEXT | ...
------ | --------- | ------------ | ---
1      | 1         | "Paris, ..." |
2      | 1         | "London..."  |
3      | 1         | "Tokyo..."   |
4      | 1         | "Moscow"     |
5      | 1         | "New York"   |
...
```

'Account'

```
ID     | CLIENT_ID | ACCOUNT_NUM  | ...
------ | --------- | ------------ | ---
1      | 1         | "0012301230" |
2      | 1         | "0172456123" |
3      | 1         | "1234001234" |
4      | 1         | "6789134834" |
5      | 1         | "2378166341" |
...
```

I don't know which response in ResultSet to expect. Usually it was just joins and everything was OK - that's first time I've started thinking about performance.

Comment: Is this a question about performance or data representation? The current query will preform just fine, as long as the client_id columns are indexed.

Comment: Provide some sample data and expected results for more detailed answers

Comment: @jarlh, that's question of performance. All columns are indexed. I'm afraid of having 10K rows in result, with 99% data just duplicates because of joins.

Comment: Even worse, 10k or rows isn't easy to read. Doesn't Oracle have some fancy functionality to return just 10 rows, with all data present?

Comment: What costs do you need to reduce? CPU consumption by SQL engine? Volume of data transferred by network? Network roundabouts? Overheads to transform raw results to something useful in external app?

Comment: @KonstantinSorokin, I have to reduce execution time :-). So mostly - CPU on SQL + network. I can easily deal with huge resultsets on client side, but having less transferred means having less to be processed.

Comment: Michael Piankov's solution seems to be optimal. Another way is to use `union all` and four simple joins with `Client`.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand the main problem is duplicating of data in result set. Because you don't need to duplicate any telephone number for any address. I think the decision may be ranking every row and join it by rank

```
with CLIENT(ID) as (
select 1 from dual)
,PROFILE (CLIENT_ID, PROFILE) as (
    select 1, 'p1' from dual union all
    select 1, 'p2' from dual union all
    select 1, 'p4' from dual
)
,ADDRESS (CLIENT_ID, ADDRESS) as (
    select 1, 'H1' from dual union all
    select 1, 'H2' from dual
)
,PHONE (CLIENT_ID, PHONE) as (
    select 1, '+13123411' from dual union all
    select 1, '+1234512344' from dual  union all
    select 1, '+12345123133' from dual  union all
    select 1, '+12345123123' from dual  union all
    select 1, '+1234512144' from dual  union all
    select 1, '+12345123123' from dual  union all
    select 1, '+1234512144' from dual  union all
    select 1, '+12345123123' from dual  union all
    select 1, '+1234512144' from dual  union all
    select 1, '+12345123123' from dual  union all
    select 1, '+1234512144' from dual
)
,ACCOUNT (CLIENT_ID, ACCOUNT) as (
    select 1, 'Acc1' from dual union all
    select 1, 'acc2' from dual
)
SELECT PROFILE ,ADDRESS ,PHONE ,ACCOUNT 
from 
(select rownum as RN, PROFILE from PROFILE PR where  PR.CLIENT_ID IN (select id from CLIENT c where c.id = 1))  a 
full outer join (select rownum as RN, ADDRESS from ADDRESS PR where  PR.CLIENT_ID IN (select id from CLIENT c where c.id = 1))  b  on a.rn = b.rn
full outer join (select rownum as RN, PHONE from PHONE PR where  PR.CLIENT_ID IN (select id from CLIENT c where c.id = 1))  c  on a.rn = c.rn
full outer join (select rownum as RN, ACCOUNT from ACCOUNT PR where  PR.CLIENT_ID IN (select id from CLIENT c where c.id = 1)) d  on a.rn = d.rn
```

Comment: Have seen this hack somewhere - looks very hacky :-(

Answer (score 1):

```
+---------+             +---------+
|         |             |         |
| Client  |------------<| Profile |
|         |             +---------+
|         |
|         |             +---------+
|         |             |         |
|         |------------<| Address |
|         |             +---------+
|         |
|         |             +---------+
|         |             |         |
|         |------------<| Account |
|         |             +---------+
+---------+
```

For what you describe, I think your data model is shown above; please correct me if I am wrong.

Assuming the above is correct, what you have here is a "chasm trap". Essentially the relationship between Address and Account (for example) is ambiguous. We know the Addresses of the client; we know the client has many accounts; but we don't know which address belongs to which accounts. For your application, that might not even make sense. In fact, re-reading your question, the solution might be as simple as three separate queries.

```
select c.*, p.*
from client c
join profile p
on c.id = client_id
;

select c.*, a.*
from client c
join address a
on c.id = client_id
;

select c.*, ac.*
from client c
join account ac
on c.id = client_id
;

        ID NAME               ID  CLIENT_ID PROFILE_TY
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1 John Doe            1          1 Primary
         1 John Doe            2          1 Secondary
         1 John Doe            3          1 Work
         1 John Doe            4          1 Office
         1 John Doe            5          1 Vacation


        ID NAME               ID  CLIENT_ID ADDRESS
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1 John Doe            1          1 Paris
         1 John Doe            2          1 London
         1 John Doe            3          1 Tokyo
         1 John Doe            4          1 Moscow
         1 John Doe            5          1 New York


        ID NAME               ID  CLIENT_ID ACCOUNT_NU
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1 John Doe            1          1 0012301230
         1 John Doe            2          1 0172456123
         1 John Doe            3          1 1234001234
         1 John Doe            4          1 6789134834
         1 John Doe            5          1 2378166341
```

Comment: But that would be 3 rountrips to the database. I wonder if there's "standard" way of solving this problem.

Comment: @DmitryZvorygin. You have not really answered the question I posed. Is there really a relationship between (for example) ACCOUNT and ADDRESS? Is the output I have shown in my example correct? Let's figure that out before worrying about round trips.

Comment: Yes, your output is correct - Profile, Account and Address are completely unrelated to each other.

Comment: @DmitryZvorygin So is there a problem with my answer as posted?

Comment: Does it answer question "should I better write multiple queries or there's simple way to make database produce less rows?"

I'm aware that there are two choices - huuge join, or multiple queries. The question is - is there any better way, and if not - which of these solutions to choose and why.

Comment: @DmitryZvorygin Why would you run a query that produces a huge number of rows? It's doing more processing than is required *and* it's the wrong results. So in my opinion (which is based on numeric facts!) thread separate queues is the way to go.